# What all the necessary settings for foundation breakpoints to work?

Tags: drupal, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I have foundation setup in my Drupal site I want to implement the breakpoints from the foundation. I have following settings for breakpoints

$breakpoints: (
  small: 0,
  medium: 640px,
  large: 1024px,
  xlarge: 1200px,
  xxlarge: 1440px,
);

$breakpoint-classes: (small medium large);

What else settings is required for breakpoints to work.

Answer (score 2):

Basically all you need is to implement those classes on your markup

Here is an example using Foundation default classes:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-6 medium-4 columns"></div>
  <div class="small-6 medium-8 columns"></div>
</div>
```

Make sure you have the viewport metatag in the `<head>` of your markup:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Also, inside any style definition you can override it using your breakpoints like this:

```
.my-background {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  @include breakpoint(medium only) {
    background-color: #000000;
  }
}
```

Whatever you define between those braces will affect screens within your "medium" breakpoint.

Check out the [documentation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/index.html)